# OpsHub creates new (virtual?) partition during migration from TFS to VSTS (VSO)?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I have migrated some projects from TFS to Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online) following [these steps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/migrate-team-projects-vs). After that I realized that I have an extra partition (with the same size and free space as the Windows partition) with a lot of folders and files created during de migration. Most of folders and files are empty. Only some of them have source files (migrated files).

Folder name examples: i10_7, i10_null, i11_7, i11_null, i20_14, i20_null, i21_14, i21_null,...
File name examples: 1457433532708.txt, 1457433533840.txt, 1457433534475.txt, 1457433534476.txt,...

So is it safe to delete the files? How can I remove this partition?

Comment: Do you mean folder or an actual physical disk partition?

Comment: @MrHinsh I mean the virtual drive and all the content. The answer is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility creates the Virtual Drive(s) to map to the folder containing TFS Workspace. This is done to overcome the 256 character in file path limit of the operating system.

Whilst the migration is running, **DO NOT** delete these folders/drive. Once, the migration is complete, the drive is automatically un-mapped. (You can then delete the contents if you wish to do so)

Comment: Yesterday, after migrations were completed the virtual drive was still mapped, after restart too. Today there is not extra drive. Thank you for reply.